# Why does Delete works for ActiveWindow but not ActiveWorkbook?

Tags: vba, excel

I don't know why this doesn't work...

```
Sheets("SampleSheet").Select
ActiveWorkbook.SelectedSheets.Delete
```

But this works...

```
Sheets("SampleSheet").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
```

In both situations, the sheet "SampleSheet" was selected, right?

Comment: `I don't know why this doesn't work...` - because `Window` has a `SelectedSheets` property and `Workbook` doesn't.

Comment: ActiveWindow relates to the application. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff835855.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As GSerg commented, it doesn't work because there is no `ActiveWorkbook.SelectedSheets` property. Someone on the Excel team wanted to make a property that returned an array of all the selected sheets. But where to put it? They could have put it at the Workbook level, but what if the user had two windows open for the same workbook? They could have different sheets selected in each window. Which window to use? So they decided to make it a property of the Window object instead.

A fine idea, maybe, but they could have put it in both places. Both the Workbook and Window object have an ActiveSheet property. When you reference `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet` it appears to be the same as `ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).ActiveSheet` and Windows(1) is always the active window. They could have done the same thing for SelectedSheets and I'd argue that they should have.

In the meantime, you can use `ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).SelectedSheets` to overcome the Excel team's lack of consistency.